# Change the font in pagination links

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the font of this pagination.

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc4V8.png)

I'm using a builder but the settings to change it are not available so I tried inspecting the code to get the right class or id and use css instead.

I'm using this code

```
.pagination li a {
font: Raleway !important;}
```

and it's still not changing. I hover over the element and I see this:
[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYtoh.png)
[pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm2Hu.png)

what should I need to change to achieve this? I'm not good with code so would appreciate any insight.

Comment: not sure about your HTML structure based on an image. What I can say is that you are using `font` where you should probably use `font-family`

Comment: @CornelRaiu  thanks for your input. i tried doing that but still no changes. i added a html snippet in the post (pic 3). would that help?

Comment: @ANGELICAViajedor please add the code in the question not as a screenshot. It's easier for others to help by quickly looking at your code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `font: Raleway !important;` you should write `font-family: Raleway !important;`

And make sure that font is available/loaded

Comment: It's also HTML structure. The CSS selector is not valid for the Beaver Builder pagination component.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code sample you posted, try this:

```
.page-numbers {font-family: Raleway;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your pic 3 I saw that you are using Beaver Builder. In order to change the font family ONLY on the page numbers, you can use:

`.fl-builder-pagination .page-numbers { font-family: Raleway; }`

As Johannes already said, you have to make sure the font family is loaded!

I just tested with the `ui-monospace` font and it works:

```
.fl-builder-pagination .page-numbers {
    font-family: ui-monospace;
}
```

Comment: It worked! I tried this style before and wondered why it's not changing the font, turns out I didn't load the font family. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @ANGELICAViajedor if it helped, please upvote and mark the accept the answer as a solution so others can benefit from it when they encounter the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your font is came from external, you should **@import** it first. Then use it as your *font-family*.

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@100&display=swap');

.pagination li a {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

If your font is in your file/downloaded file, you should make an name for your font and use it.

```
<style>
@font-face {
   font-family:'Myfont-Raleway';
   src: url('myfonts/Raleway.ttf')
}

.pagination li a {
font-family: 'Myfont-Raleway';
}
</style>
```

use **!important** just to be sure it read the font.

Comment: The above answer is just a reference, maybe you are using the wrong class, so make sure you use the correct class when calling the *style*.